# "ImportError: No module named fiona" (post-installation of package)

Tags: qgis, python

I'm in need of the Fiona and Shapely modules to develop a QGIS 2 plugin, and thus downloaded them from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal and installed them. I have no trouble importing shapely, but importing fiona gives me "ImportError: No module named fiona"

I am wondering if there's a step I'm missing besides the installation of the correct version (for 32-bit Windows and Python 2.7, using the standalone installer for QGIS) before being able to import them via the QGIS Python console.

Comment: Please add information about your OS and how you installed QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona, it says "requires GDAL". Did you install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal too?